# how to use php string function in twig template engine

Tags: php, django-templates, template-engine, twig

I want to use few php string functions in twig. For e.g.

How to write below code in twing?

```
if (!empty($message) && substr_count($message, 'blabla')) {
   ....
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and that's the whole point of twig.
Template should only take care of displaying data.

In that specific case, you could create a TWIG variable, and simply pass TRUE or FALSE, so that you twig code would look like:

```
{% if display_message %}
...
{% enfif %}
```

You can look at the list of expressions that are available in the twig template, strstr_count is not part of them :( http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#expressions

Answer (score 0):

Use filters:

```
{% if message is not empty and ... %}
 ...
{% endif %}
```

I think there is not a substr_count equivalent for twig, you can either make the test and pass the result to the template or create a twig extension and implement it yourself

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation